# Имя отсутствует в текущем контексте C#

Tags: c#

Есть форма `FormData` и форма `FormResult`.
На первой есть `textBox` и `Button`.Обе формы в одном namespace. На первой форме у кнопки есть обработчик:

```
private void resButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string path = textBox.Text;
        FormResult res = new FormResult();
        res.Show(); 
}
```

В namespace есть класс `DataClass` для обработки `.xml` файла, содержащий метод, принимающий путь из `textBox`. Этот метод мы вызываем для заполнения таблици на форме `FormResult`(метод читает данные из файла и по ним строит `DataGridView`):

```
DataClass class = new DataClass();

BindingList<Row> data = new BindingList<Row>();
foreach (Row row in class.MakeRows(path))
{
    data.Add(row);
}
```

При вызове метода происходит ошибка: Ошибка CS0103: *Имя "path" отсутствует в текущем контексте*.

Обработчик `private`, а значит путь не виден другой форме. Решил попробовать вместо path использовать `textBox.Text`, но для этого что надо создать конструктор формы (`FormResult`) и передать ему ссылку на первую форму, используя `this`? Может и не так, но я попробовал.

Comment: А... так вы  "path" обьявили в зоне видимости resButtonClick? Его можно использовать исключительно в resButtonClick. А за его пределами - нельзя. Читайте "область видимости переменной"

Comment: С другой стороны, может ли вторая форма обратится к textButton на первой?

Comment: Читайте "c# область видимости переменной", без понимания этого вам будет тяжело писать программы в дальнейшем.

Comment: Может, потому что она обьявлена в *другой* области видимости, более широкой.

Comment: Видите ли, я передавал в метод сразу значение `textBox.Text`, но он не виден. Это я и хотел сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать передать параметр через конструктор.

В `FormResult` сделать так:

```
private string _path;
. . .

public FormResult(string path)
{
    . . . // какой-то стандартный код из шаблона.
    this._path = path; 
}
```

В `FormData`:

```
string path = textBox.Text;
FormResult res = new FormResult(path);
res.Show();
```

Но, вообще это не совсем удачный вариант. На будущее, лучше задействовать паттерны наподобие MVP или MVVM. Но, для простой программки сойдёт.